# relation between biggest singular value and the sum of all singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, singular-values, matrix-analysis

Given a matrix $A$, its singular values are denoted as $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_n$. Since in most of the case, the biggest singular value is much larger than others, I just want to know whether there are some bounds to depict such relation. For example, I want to find something like $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i\le H\sigma_1$$
Is there any $H$ that we can use?

Comment: What do you mean by "in most of the cases"? What is your metric for "most" here?

Comment: your LHS is scalar and RHS is matrix, maybe you make your RHS $\mathrm{tr}(H\sigma_1)$?

Comment: I think if you don't have additional information on $A$, then best bound is $\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i\le n\sigma_1$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  My case is on a sub stochastic matrix. But I think for matrix we always meet, the first singular value is always much larger than others.

Comment: @Lee  if it is a sub stochastic matrix what conclusion can we get? $n\sigma_1$ is too large for my case.

Comment: @maple you can't improve the bound because, for example, there are substochastic multiples of the identity matrix.